# android java array of paint

Tags: java, android, arrays, bitmap

i am making a game and i trying to make bitmaps dissapear or appear anyway for some reason when i use paint as 1 object it works but when i add a array paint(fro each bitmap) it crashes
here is the lines i used with it:

```
//in MainActivity class
Paint[] paintanswer;
//in oncreate
paintanswer=new Paint[answerlength];

//in the draw func
for(int i=0;i<answerlength;i++){
                paintanswer[i].setAlpha(answeralpha[i]);
                canvas.drawBitmap(answerbitmapscaled[i],(float) (((cwidth/2)-((answerlength*answersize)/4)-answersize/4)+i*(answersize/2)),(float) (cwidth/2), paintanswer[i]);
```

the answer length is the length i get from other activity accordingly i set the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An array in Java is just a container with a certain amount of slots for elements of a certain type. In your case a container that can store for example 20 `Paint` elements, however, it is completely empty. You have to fill the array with elements if you want to use them later on:

```
paintanswer = new Paint[answerlength];
for (int i = 0; i < answerlength; i++)
    paintanswer[i] = new Paint();
```